# Magento 2 - How To Generate Custom Data Fixture For Integration Testing

Tags: orders, testing, setup-script

I'm required to generate 1000+ orders to test an integration + address verification.

[I've come across this data generation technique](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-perf-data.html#config-cli-gen-orders) in my search and wish to create my own data fixture based off:

```bash
setup/performance-toolkit/profiles/ce/small.xml
setup/src/Magento/Setup/Fixtures/OrdersFixture.php
```

With key differences being:

1. Randomly generate Customer Addresses.
2. Randomise order status.

My question is how is this achieved via a custom module, and how is the relationship between `setup/src/Magento/Setup/Fixtures/OrdersFixture.php` & `setup/performance-toolkit/profiles/ce/small.xml` established?